# Разбить строку на части из БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, строки

Здравствуйте, интересует следующий **вопрос**:
Как разбить строку приходящую из БД, для последующего занесения частей этой строки в таблицу, где часть 1 - колонка 1 и т.д? Например есть строка `Материал: сталь;`, далее `Страна производитель: Россия;` (это все одна строка) так вот мне нужно `Материал и Страна производитель` занести в ячейки слева, а `сталь и Россия` в соответствующие правые ячейки, как это можно сделать? Надеюсь понятно смог объяснить.

Comment: Странный тип хранения данных. ну ды ладно

Comment: @dDevil я знаю что рационально создать справочники, но в качестве изучения решил что нужно сделать этим способом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `explode('разделитель', $srt)` разобьет строку на массив.

Бейте 2 раза. Сначала с разделителем `';'`, потом элементы массива по `':'`

Comment: Как мне потом эти части в таблицу вписать подскажите

Comment: $a = explode(';', $srt); как елементы массива просто <td><?php echo $a[0];?></td>

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо)

Comment: незачто, но я бы не советовал так хранить данные, слишком костыльный вывод получается...

Comment: я все понимаю, это исключительно в рамках обучения)

Answer (score 3):

Если кратенько - то так:

```
$dbRows = array_map(
  function($row){ 
    return  array_map('trim', explode(':', $row));
  },
  explode(';', $sourceString)
);
```

explode - разбивает строку в массив

array_map - к каждому элементу применяет ф-ю